# Context menu for windows bash admin

Tags: windows, bash, registry, contextmenu, admin

I would like to be able to open the windows bash terminal from windows explorer with a context menu. Much like you can do in Ubuntu. I have created a subkey in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory/Background/shell` with the command:

```
powershell -c start -verb runas cmd '/c start /D "%V" bash.exe'
```

This works well for opening the bash as admin in most directories, but it crashes if the directory has a space in it. It seems to be that bash only takes part of the string, and then can't find the directory to navigate to. I've tried escape quotes around the `%V`, e.g `"""%V"""` but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this: `PowerShell -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -Command Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c start /B /D \"%V\" bash.exe' -Verb runas`. This escapes the double quotes with backslashes to sneak them by PowerShell's initial command-line parsing. Running PowerShell with a hidden window and no profile should clear it from the screen as fast as possible. We can't reuse its console via `-NoNewWindow` because "runas" requires a new console. But by using CMD's `/B` option for the `start` command, we at least avoid needlessly creating a third console for bash.

Comment: Don't write to keys in HKCR. It's just a view that searches in "HKCU\Software\Classes" and then "HKLM\Software\Classes". It's meant for reading configuration, not writing. The result of writing to HKCR depends on what's already defined in HKCU and HKLM.

Comment: Here's an alternate approach that avoids PowerShell. Create a key named "HKLM\Software\Classes\Directory\background\shell\runas" and give it a default value like "Open in bash as administrator". Create a subkey named "command" and give it a default value of `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c start /B /D "%V" bash.exe`. Change the path to cmd.exe if you have a different system directory. It has to be the fully-qualified path to cmd.exe.

Comment: Just tried your last approach and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate approach that avoids PowerShell. Create a key named "HKLM\Software\Classes\Directory\background\shell\runas" and give it a default value like "Open in bash as administrator". Create a subkey named "command" and give it a default value of "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c start /B /D "%V" bash.exe. Change the path to cmd.exe if you have a different system directory. It has to be the fully-qualified path to cmd.exe.  – eryksun